# Should I apply the same practice to PHP access specifiers as I do to Java specifiers?

Tags: php

I'm currently doing a tutorial on PHP and it has me create a class Person which might represent a user on a website.

There are two public fields (`$firstname` and `$lastname`) and the tutorial has me access them using `$some_person->firstname`.

I know in Java we would most likely want to make these fields private and use getters and setters to access them. Should I apply this same practice to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - PHP5+ supports `public/protected/private` methods in classes. You don't need to design getters/setters but if the class grows/adds functionality it'll be safer than letting people call the properties directly.

Comment: If I don't design getters and setters how else could I access a private field?

Comment: *private/protected* fields need them if you need the data publicly, of course. Some people debate whether getters/setters are necessary if your properties are *public*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general properties should be made `protected` or `private` and getters and setters offered. This will allow you to add in type hints in the setter signature or validation in the setter body, which will make it harder for bad data to slip into properties unnoticed. I tend to recommend this approach even if "you don't need it now" - you may do so later.

The argument against `public` properties in PHP is just the same as it is in Java: it opens up the "black box" of the class to the outside world, and starts to break down the encapsulation that classes are meant to offer in the first place.

Classes are usually meant to be extended, which has a bearing on whether properties should be `protected` or `private`. If child classes are trusted (e.g. part of the same codebase) the developer may be happy to allow direct access to the property, in which case it can be `protected`. However, if the code is intended for release (e.g. as a F/OSS library) then there's an argument for forcing child classes use the getter and setter methods, in which case the properties should be `private`.